# How to use custom ruby and rails for different applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, redmine

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I also have ruby and rails installed on my system using the **rvm**. This is a custom installation and not the ubuntu package.

I want to install Redmine on my system. However, when I install it using

```
aptitude install redmine redmine-mysql
```

it does not find ruby or rails as it is not installed via `aptitude`. Is it possible to make Redmine use my custom installation and not install the default ruby/rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not install it via `aptitude` as they often have quite outdated stuff for Ruby.  If you want to run Redmine in your RVM environment:

- Download Redmine:
  http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download
- `rvm use whatever_ruby_you_want`
- `cd /path/to/redmine`
- `bundle install`

  Then follow the instructions [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) to set up your database.